# DataGridView.Columns Throwing Exception When DataSource is Set

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a TabControl and a set of tabs. Each tab displays a different DataGridView. When the application runs I can see each table perfectly. Unfortunately when I try to set the `.Frozen` attribute on a column, it throws a null exception. I don't understand how this is possible since "Portfolio" exists on each table. Furthermore when I try to freeze by index, instead of by column name, I get an index out of bounds exception. It's as though the columns don't exist until they are displayed.

How can I freeze the first column programatically?

I'm also getting a column count of 0. `dv.ColumnCount`

[image]

Comment: If the column count is zero, that's your answer. `_rlvd.Tables[i]` doesn't contain a column called `Portfolio` because it doesn't contain any columns at all.

Comment: But when I run a count on the columns of `_rlvd.Tables[i]`, it gives me 20, which is what I expect.

Comment: My mistake, I meant to say `dv` doesn't contain any columns. You have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to false. So even if `_rlvd.Tables[i]` has columns, unless you generate them manually, your `DataGridView` isn't going to have any columns. Do you create the columns manually somewhere else?

Comment: @PatrickTucci I do create them manually elsewhere. I don't think it has to do with AutoGenerateColumns. I removed it and it still didn't work. I found the answer to my question and will add it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataGridViewColumns` aren't created when the `DataTable` is assigned and the `Handle` of the `DataGridView` is not yet created.

To force the columns to be created, you can use:

```
public static void refresh(DataGridView view, DataTable table) {
    bool origAuto = view.AutoGenerateColumns;
    view.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    view.DataSource = table;
    view.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
    view.AutoGenerateColumns = origAuto;
}
```

Comment: Works for me. What does BindingContext do exactly? I didn't understand when reading the documentation. And why do you care about restoring the original AutoGeneratedColumns property?

Comment: Setting the `BindingContext` is the easiest way to make the `DataGridView` call its `private void RefreshColumnsAndRows()` method. You can look at the `C# DataGridView` source code at `referencesource.microsoft.com` and search for `OnBindingContextChanged`.

Comment: As for `AutoGenerateColumns`, I think it happened to me that the `DataGridView` decided to regenerate the columns, thereby disposing the original `DataGridViewColumn` objects, which lead to problems since those objects were expected to persist. So it's better to keep the setting `false`, or put it back to its original value. However, just fyi, `DataGridViewRows` should always be treated as temporary, the `DataGridView` creates them as needed, and disposes old ones it no longer needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my desired results by adding a method to the `VisibleChanged` event.

`dv.VisibleChanged += (s, e) => { dv.Columns["Portfolio"].Frozen = true; };`

[image]